Run-time error '7': Out of memory when copying data with leading text === from another workbook
We run reports on a customer facing database. We use the data from those reports in various other reports, all done through Excel and macros.
These reports have been running for about two years until this past Saturday when we started getting:

Run-time error '7':
Out of memory when copying data from another workbook

A customer prefaced an entry with three equals signs (===) before any text and my assumption is Excel was trying to solve the equation instead of copying the data.
It happens if I pare the data down to just that row.
I would like to build something to account for that.
The code that is called.
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange
    RawDataMR.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With

I tried setting calculation to manual.
I tried turning off calculation for that particular sheet.
I'm hoping there is a way to keep it from trying to read that as a formula.
My only other thought is to build a routine that inspects the contents of each cell and strips out any character other than an alphanumeric character but that seems problematic as there are typically 7k lines and I'm pretty sure it would still hiccup when it hit that cell.

Thanks. It happens if I pair the data down to just that row.

RawDataMR.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).NumberFormat = "@", before transferring the value.

@BigBen Perfect! Thanks a bunch!

The fix I was looking for was more simple than I hoped. Thanks to BigBen for the reply.
RawDataMR.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).NumberFormat = "@"

, before transferring the value. –
BigBen

Side note: this does apply text formatting to everything, which may not be desired for numeric values, for example.

Here's a more targeted approach.  It will be much faster looping over arr than cell-by-cell over the source range.
'example usage
Sub Tester()
    '...
    '...
    TransferClean ActiveWorkbook.sheets(1).UsedRange, RawDataMR.Range("A1")
    '...
End Sub


Sub TransferClean(rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range)
    Dim arr, r As Long, c As Long, v
    arr = rngSrc.Value
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            v = arr(r, c)
            'if it looks like a formula, make it Text
            If v Like "=*" Then arr(r, c) = "'" & v
        Next c
    Next r
    rngDest.Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
End Sub



It looks like the issue is happening because Excel is trying to treat any
cell that starts with === as a formula, which is causing the error

You can loop through the cells and check if they start with = (which
includes ===), and then add an apostrophe (') at the start to make sure
Excel treats it as plain text instead of a formula



Yes, I am certain it is an issue with Excel trying to run it as a formula. I will try your suggestion of adding an apostrophe but was really hoping to not have to go that route as it can be a lot of data for it to parse through and I would have to do it in the file we are opening to copy from which adds other complexities to the way we are currently working.
